# AngularJS - change $location silently - remove query string

Tags: angularjs

Is there any way to silently change the route in the url bar using angular?

The user clicks a link for the email that goes to:

```
/verificationExecuted?verificationCode=xxxxxx
```

When the page loads I want to read the verificationCode and then clear it:

```
 if($location.path() == '/verificationExecuted'){
     this.registrationCode = this.$location.search()["verificationCode"];
     this.$location.search("verificationCode", null); //Uncomment but make this silent!

     if(registrationCode != null) {
         ....
     }
     else $location.path("/404");      
 }
```

What happens when I clear it is the remaining part of the route ("/verificationExecuted") remains buts the route re-triggers so it comes around again with no verificationCode and goes straight to 404.

I want to remove the code without doing anything else.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can always set the [`reloadOnSearch`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.$routeProvider) option on your route to be `false.`

It will prevent the route from reloading if only the query string changes:

```
$routeProvider.when("/path/to/my/route",{
   controller: 'MyController',
   templateUrl: '/path/to/template.html',
   //Secret Sauce
   reloadOnSearch: false
});
```

Comment: you are a life saver!

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
$location.url($location.path())
```

See [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) for more details about $location

Comment: This will reload the route

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement for one of my projects.

What I did in such a case was make use of a service.

```
app.factory('queryData', function () {
    var data;

    return {
        get: function () {
            return data;
        },
        set: function (newData) {
            data = newData
        }
    };
});
```

This service was then used in my controller as:

```
app.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'queryData',
    function ($scope, $location, queryData) {
        var queryParam = $location.search()['myParam'];
        if (queryParam) {
            //Store it
            queryData.set(queryParam);
            //Reload same page without query argument
            $location.path('/same/path/without/argument');
        } else {
            //Use the service
            queryParam = queryData.get();
            if (queryParam) {
                //Reset it so that the next cycle works correctly
                queryData.set();
            }
            else {
                //404 - nobody seems to have the query
                $location.path('/404');
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding a method that changes the path and canceling the event.

```js
 public updateSearch(){

            var un = this.$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', (e)=> {
                
                e.preventDefault();
                
                un();
                
            });
            
            this.$location.search('new',search.searchFilter);
            
            if (!keep_previous_path_in_history) this.$location.replace();
            
}
```